# Linking a java project as a dependency to a psgi plugin project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi-bundle

I have an osgi plugin project as part of my development. There is another project, which is just a normal java project, which i am just using as a library. How do I add my java project as a dependency to my plugin project, so that the classes inside my java project are usable within the plugin project code..

Answer (score 0):

Everything must be in a plugin to be usable from an Eclipse plugin.

You could package your Java code up in to a jar and include it in your plugin, or make a separate plugin containing the Java code.

Comment: That creates a problem. May be my bad. I have an osgi plugin bundle, from which I am accessing a method in a jar in my classpath. Within the same plugin project I have written another class which implements an interface defined inside the jar. Now the flow is - i invoke the method given in the jar library and it will do some processing and invoke the interface implementation of his that i have written. Here when the jar tries to invoke the implementation that I have written, he always complaints about ClassNotFoundExcption.